# How to use Glide within screenshot-tests-for-android tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

Hi im new to Android Unit Testing and try to make some Screenshot tests with facebooks : screenshot-tests-for-android. So the first components are fine but now im on an component that utilize Glide to load an Picture. How can i use it in screenshot-tests-for-android ? For now i got this exception

Task :app:connectedDevDebugAndroidTest
Starting 5 tests on EML-L29 - 8.1.0

ViewModelTests emptyViewModel[EML-L29 - 8.1.0] FAILED

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on the main thread

at com.bumptech.glide.util.Util.assertMainThread(Util.java:142)

Answer (score -1):

Probably just use @UiThread on the test. The default Test Runner that Android provides will recognize that annotation and run the entire test on the UI thread.